# Rendering a Partial from another Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, render, partial-views

I'm Trying to render a Partial from my App/view/pins folder to my
app/view/layout folder (My menu).

Basically i'm trying to render my _form.html.erb to a **Modal** which is
triggered with a button on my Menu.

I'm using Bootstrap.

Every time i give my modal the code:

```
<%= render 'pins/form' %>
```

i'm getting:

```
NoMethodError in Pins#index
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

**I searched A LOT and EVERYWHERE but couldn't fix it..**
Can anybody Help me?

(Git repo-> https://github.com/Theminijohn/Amphitryon)

**Errors:**
The Error Trace -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjRcK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `@pins` in the simple form definition with `current_user.pins.new`

Comment: Oh god !! IT WORKED !!! i dont now if this's a good way but for the moment everything seems perfect. Thank you

Comment: Crashes the Application if someones Logging out. I think because of the current_user.. :(

Comment: WOW, i had the same idea :) it worked cause of you're suggestion of current_user.pins.new.. Thank you Anurag :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'pins/form' %>
```

**Edit**

I looked at your code. In your pins/form partial you're referring to `@pin` instance variable, which may not be available in your partial. That's why your stack trace is referring to a `NilClass`.

I think you can try to pass `@pin` as a local partial variable in one of these ways:

```
<%= render :partial => 'pins/form', :locals => { :pin => @pin } %>
```

or (shorthand syntax)

```
<%= render "pins/form", :pin => @pin %>
```

Comment: Im rendering the button in my Navbar, and storing the modal div there also.. either ways dont work :(

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand `render @pins` is doing this:

```
render :partial => 'pin', :collection => @pins
```

whereby each pin is passed as a **local variable**.

However, your partial references the **instance variable** `@pin` which, unless explicitly assigned in the controller, will return *nil*:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@pin, #...snipped...
```

Change it to the **local variable**, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for(pin, #...snipped...
```

Comment: If i change the form it give's me -> undefined local variable or method `pin'. BUT if leave the form @pin and add the render form you gave me in my modal FOR THE FIRST TIME i see (at least) a rendering, NOT the form but the PINS.. How can i render the partial _from.html.erb ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**How i Fixed it**
Thank you for all your Help, without you guys i wouldn't have figured it out.

1.) I Changed the form from @pin to

```
current_user.pins.new
```

2.) Than, because the modal got rendered without the user being logged in and that caused an error i wrapped the modal in an if statement

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
...form code...
<% end %>
```

and everything worked perfectly.